# declaring empty byte - Nullable object must have a value?

Tags: c#, linq, byte

I'm still very new to C# and would appreciate any help with my code.

I'm creating a user profile page and am getting the error "Nullable object must have a value" on "photo = (byte)user.Photo;" in the following code. I assume it's because I declared "photo = 0;" How do I add a value to it?

Update:

Here's the entire method

```
      public static bool UserProfile(string username, out string userID, out string email, out byte photo)
    {

        using (MyDBContainer db = new MyDBContainer())
        {

            userID = "";
            photo = 0;
            email = "";
            User user = (from u in db.Users
                         where u.UserID.Equals(username)
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                photo = (byte)user.Photo;
                email = user.Email;
                userID = user.UserID;
                return true; // success!
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `user.Photo`, `Nullable<byte>` or `byte?`?

Comment: Where are you declaring `photo`? Is the error at compile time or execution time? What's the type of `user.Photo`? Can you create a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: `user.Photo` evaluates to `null` (that is what causes this sort of Exception message, when `Value` is invoked upon a null nullable). Try: `user.Photo ?? 0`, although do understand the implications .. or declare `photo` as the same type as well.

Comment: I just edited my post to show the entire method

Comment: @Rac28 you still need to tell use what the type of `user.Photo` is.

Comment: Somewhere you have a variable or field of a nullable type. I would still guess that `user.Photo` is not actually of type `byte` but rather of type `byte?`. Otherwise, the error message makes no sense. Also, why would you cast to `byte` if `user.Photo` already had the type `byte`?

Comment: If your `user.Photo` is nullable, you could simply check, whether it has a property `user.Photo.HasValue`...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting error for this one...

```
  if (user != null)
        {
            photo = (byte)user.Photo;
            email = user.Email;
            userID = user.UserID;
            return true; // success!
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

If yes then just replace it with...

```
  if (user != null)
        {
            photo = user.Photo== null ? null : (byte)user.Photo;
            email = user.Email;
            userID = user.UserID;
            return true; // success!
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```